# Is it possible to implement web push notification without using FCM?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

We would like to implement web push notifications, for some websites we have developed. Most of these websites have been created with Spring MVC. I would like to understand if FCM is the best option for implementing web push notifications or are there other options (without any third party integrations)? We need to be able to send the notifications even when the webapp is not running.

FCM seems to be easier but we would like to know if there are any downsides to it as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of notifications you want to implement.

For **on-site notifications**, you can use websockets or SSE. You can build it in house. Then you can optionally display the notifications using the w3c notifications api.

For **off-site notifications** (like FCM), then you need to use the browser push service. The browser push service is hardcoded in the browser and you can't change it. However note that there are two different kinds of web push services:

- the **browser push service (you can't change it)**: e.g. FCM for Chrome, Mozilla autopush for Firefox, APNs for Safari, etc.
- an optional **web push service** that deals with those services for you by creating **a new layer of abstraction**: e.g. Pushpad, FCM

Note that I have mentioned FCM in both cases, because it started in the first role and then added also the second role.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. we are looking for off-site notifications. Will FCM work only with chrome or other browsers too. It seems no as per your point 2a, but am not clear with 2b. Can you pls elaborate more on the optional web push service?

Comment: after reading more abt web-push, am assuming you are referring to using VAPID, which means I do not need to register with FCM at all for push. And that is supposed to work for both chrome and firefox (and for other supported browsers in future). Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, if you use VAPID, which is the standard, you don't need to sign up to FCM. VAPID works out of the box with all the standard push services (Mozilla autopush, FCM, etc.)

Comment: does VAPID work even the web app is not running in the browser?

Comment: Yes, VAPID is a standard which is part of the Push API, which is meant exactly to deliver notifications even when the website is closed.

Comment: Basically you have two options: 1. **use the standard and deal directly with every browser push service** (i.e. Mozilla autopush for Firefox, FCM for Chrome, etc.) 2. use a web push service to have an additional layer of abstraction: in that case you need to **sign up to a service like Pushpad or FCM** that act as a proxy towards the correct browser push service